# onRequest() is not working in Play! framework 2.5.x

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I want to execute business logic before a request is dispatched to an action.

This is my code:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    public Action onRequest(Http.Request request, Method actionMethod){
        System.out.println("before each request..." + request.toString());
        return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
    }

}
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Global` is deprecated in Play 2.5 as part of the move away from global state.

Use filters instead.  You can find a detailed breakdown in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters).

Comment: JavaHttpFilters is not working when I'm calling an API from some other play! Framework app or an Android app

Comment: Sounds like you haven't defined the filter chain.

Comment: I'm new to play framework so I'm facing problems. What if I create my Custom routes where I can route my API requests

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions.  If you're having general issues, head over to the support group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework